# Compilation errors on GooglePlacesAutocomplete framework after XCode upgrade

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-autocomplete

I am using `GooglePlacesAutocomplete` API's in my iOS App written in swift. It was compiled before, but recently after bunch of `Xcode` upgrades, it is now giving me bunch of compile-time errors (around 47 errors) all on **GooglePlacesAutocomplete.swift** file.

Update:
  Xcode version 9.2
  Pod version 1.3.1
  Swift version 3.2 and 4 both

[image]

Comment: Need to update your pod.

Comment: I did “pod install” but get those errors.

Comment: You added a manually so that framework is not supported in your latest Xcode. Try to using with pod that added a supported version as per your Xcode.

Comment: I did "pod update" but still getting the same errors. Don't know how to fix the errors.